# Does MVC Mini Profiler monitor requests to subdomains

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subdomain, mvc-mini-profiler

I have asset domains created on my machine that are basically routed through the hosts file to localhost itself. Now when I activate MVC mini profiler on my local website it is not capturing any requests to these asset domains.

Is this a bug or an issue that only I am facing? Can I get it to monitor the same in anyway.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "asset domains" what do they serve up? Is it just images, or is asp.net actually serving up content?

Comment: Do all of your asset domains have miniprofiler installed, and properly configured?

Comment: These asset domains are routed to one server.. These are domains that map to the same server

Answer (score 0):

MVC Mini Profiler is not capturing HTTP requests; it works inside your MVC application and only intercepts/profiles requests to controllers' actions of your MVC application.

What exactly do you need to profile?

Comment: these are my controllers actions.. in this case my asset domains basically serve some dynamically generated images..